# Playframework: InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create a simple login based on the Zentask sample, however I'm getting a runtime exception in smgts2\app\controllers\Application.java at line 43.

```
public static Result authenticate() {
  Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest(); //Line 43
  if(loginForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
  } else {
    session("user_name", loginForm.get().user_name);
    return redirect(
```

I've uploaded the files in github: https://github.com/gscruz/smgts2-start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134105/playframework-runtimeexception-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Can you please answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your project on GitHub, I think the main issues are with the JPA annotations on your `Accounts` model class that models your `user_account` database table. The mappings on your model class get exercised when you bind the form data to a Login object, since `Login.validate` queries `user_account`.

Since the name of your class does not match the name of the table, you'll need a JPA `@Table` annotation to explicitly state the mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
public class Accounts extends Model
```

You'll also need `@Column` annotations for the fields whose names don't match up with their corresponding columns. Give that a go and see if it gets you any further.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I've adjusted the codes in model class "Accounts" and the structure for user_account table instead of using @Columns.