# Play Framework Error on Login.class/Form "RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

My application has been running for a month now.  As of today, when I attempt to login, I am receiving this error:
RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

It is occurring in my Application.java controller:
[image]

This code is from the Play Start App template/seed.

Here is the Login class:

```
/**
 * Login class used by Login Form.
 */
public static class Login {

    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;
    String errMessage = "";

    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    /**
     * Validate the authentication.
     *
     * @return null if validation ok, string with details otherwise
     */
    public String validate() {
        Logger.debug("Login - validate()");
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = User.authenticate(email, password);
            SessionData createUserSession = AccessMiddleware.createUserSession(user);
            AuditLog.setLog(user.fullname, user.getEmail(), "Login", "validate()", "User authenticated",
                    user.fullname);

            // Let's setup the Workflow Session...              
            WorkflowUser workflowUser = WorkflowUser.initialize(email);
            WorkflowSessionData workflowCreateUserSession = WorkflowSessionAccess.createUserSession(workflowUser);

        } catch (AppException e) {
            errMessage = Messages.get("error.technical");
            return errMessage;
        }
        if (user == null) {
            errMessage = Messages.get("invalid.user.or.password");
            return errMessage;
        } else if (!user.validated) {
            errMessage = Messages.get("account.not.validated.check.mail");
            return errMessage;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the authenticate function:

```
/**
     * Handle login form submission.
     *
     * @return Dashboard if auth OK or login form if auth KO
     */
public Result authenticate() {
    String errorMessage = "";

    Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
    Logger.debug("authenticate");
    Form<Register> registerForm = form(Register.class);

    if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        Logger.debug("authenticate - bad request");
        // return badRequest(index.render(registerForm, loginForm));
        return badRequest(auth.render(loginForm));
        // return badRequest(index.render());
        // return badRequest();
    } else {
        Logger.debug("authenticate - good request");
        session("email", loginForm.get().email);

        boolean isAuth = AccessMiddleware.isAuthenticated();
        RoleType role = AccessMiddleware.getSessionRole();

        // Let's see if we need to redirect...
        String cardKey = openCardKey;
        if (cardKey != null) {
            if (!cardKey.equals("")) {
                // Let's redirect...
                // First remove the session variable...
                openCardKey = "";
                return redirect(routes.Application.openCard(cardKey));
            }
        }

        switch (role) {
        case USER:
            return GO_USER;

        case ADMIN:
            return GO_ADMIN;

        default:
            return GO_HOME;

        }
    }
}
```

I have not changed any of the code and this error just started today.

I found a few posts and tried the solutions, but still getting the error:

[Playframework: [RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134105/playframework-runtimeexception-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception)

[Playframework: InvocationTargetException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087011/playframework-invocationtargetexception)

I have cleaned, refreshed, and rebuilt the project in Eclipse.  I have removed the target folder and recreated.  I have no errors in the project.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What's your play version?

Comment: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")`

Comment: It looks like it is a problem on validation. Try to write getters and setters for your fields. It is the only part on play that I've found that could throw this exception.

Comment: I moved my Play version to 2.5.12 and my Scala to 2.11.7 and it now works.

Comment: could you add stack trace from the server console ?